# PHP OOP: How does this code work?

Tags: php, oop, autoload

I'm kind of new to PHP5/OOP and can't really get my head around how the following code works. Found it on the PHP.net documentation when researching the __autoload()-function.

How shall I call this? `new MyClass1();` Or `autoloader::model('myModel');` ?

[The snippet:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#99173)

```
class autoloader {

    public static $loader;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (self::$loader == NULL)
        self::$loader = new self();

        return self::$loader;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'model'));
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'helper'));
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'controller'));
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'library'));
    }

    public function library($class)
    {
        set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/lib/');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.library.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }

    public function controller($class)
    {
        $class = preg_replace('/_controller$/ui','',$class);

        set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/controller/');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.controller.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }

    public function model($class)
    {
        $class = preg_replace('/_model$/ui','',$class);

        set_include_path( dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR.'/model/');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.model.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }

    public function helper($class)
    {
        $class = preg_replace('/_helper$/ui','',$class);

        set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/helper/');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.helper.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$autoloader = autoloader::init();
```

That will give you the autoloader instance. This class wants to be a singleton.

All __autoloader is is a last minute attempt by php to find a class that hasn't been included yet.  If you have a good naming/directory structure you won't need to worry about including/requiring any of your own classes...the autoloader will do it for you.

if you wanted to call the model function:

```
$autoloader->model('Model');
```

This would be done after calling the static init() function from above.